# How to show both currencies at once in the node page for price field

Tags: commerce

I am using Drupal commerce kickstart, Here I have two types of currencies like $ and INR. In the node page I am showing INR currency by default. Using Curreny Selector Module I am showing Dropdown to select the currency. If currency selected by user then calculated $ currency is showing fine. But here I need to show both prices at once. For example, "Rs.1205 & $20" at once without selecting the currency from dropdown. I am loading this node page programmatically. So I want to load the currency programmatically which is converting through European Bank. Any Suggestions please.

Answer (score 0):

[Commerce Multicurrency](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_multicurrency) does exactly that.

> This module enhances some of the multi-currency capabilities of Drupal
>   Commerce.
>
> Current features:
>
> 1. UI for fine granular definition of exchange rates.
>      (Every currency combination can be defined separately if needed)
>      Synchronization of currency exchange rates directly from the European Central Bank (ECB).
> 2. UI to specify which rates shall be synchronized and which are handled manually.
> 3. Generation of currency specific price fields inclusive generation of rule-set to handle them.
> 4. hooks for easy integration of custom currency exchange rate sources.